# Nodejs Loopback how to access api end points on live server?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to deploy a Loopback project to live server, all works well on local. On server, after running node ., I get the console log of:
Web server listening at: http://domainname:3000
Browse your REST API at http://domainname:3000/explorer

So it looks like the server is running.

Problem is that I get no response from the server. Neither from domain:3000 or /explorer or any endpoint I created.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and incomplete. Please include in the question, part of the code that relates to the problem.

Comment: Ok. After I uploaded the project on the server, I run the command "node ." to start de loopback server. The server starts and prints to the console: Web server listening at: http://mydomain.ro:3000
Browse your REST API at http://mydomain.ro:3000/explorer. Then when I try to access any end point, I get connection timeout. https://ibb.co/hs8tAU

Comment: If you are using AWS EC2 for deploy nodejs server Than this link my help you : `https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to deploy my code. Some of the possible solutions to the problem depending on where and how you are deploying it-

1. Check if your security group allows connections on port 3000. AWS EC2 by default closes all ports except port 80. You might have to add an exception to your security group and allow port 3000 to be accessed from everywhere.
2. If you are using a container, check if your container has the ports open and if the container port is accessible by the hardware hosting the container. On Azure, I faced this problem as Azure Web App Container Service by default only listens to port 80 and 8080. So I had to modify my code such that it can use the default `NODE_ENV.PORT` or `8080`.